# Is there a way to change the screen orientation in Win8 via program?

Tags: windows-8, orientation

I am curious if there is a way to change the screen orientation directly via code, e.g.

```
rotate 90
rotate 0

rotate90, no further automatic rotation
```

I am not looking for shortcuts on Keyboard nor changes in the SystemSettings cause I wanna do it via code. Any ideas how to change them (i.e. orientation and the setting reg. *automatic orientation*)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with [iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm), although its pretty old and doesn't support additional feature like switch off automatic rotation. Anyway a solution. Newer or better solutions are welcomed.